# Problem with using Local Storage in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am having this problem using local storage in React where every time I try to store an array of objects in local storage,

I either get an error saying objects are not valid as React child or an infinite loop within `useEffect`. I am trying to store an array of objects which hold an id and value in local storage whenever a user adds a new checkbox using `useEffect`.

What is the best approach to persist data using local storage in React? I am stuck on this problem for a very long time and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { Delete, Refresh, Add } from "../components/Actions";
    import { Header } from "../components/Header";
    import { PriorityLists } from "../components/PriorityLists";
    import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
    
    function Task() {
      const [toDo, setToDo] = useState([]);
      const [idsToRefresh, setIdsToRefresh] = useState([]);
      const [filter_items, setFilterItems] = useState(false);
      const [ids, setIds] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(toDo));
      });
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (toDo[0] !== undefined) {
          const value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
          setToDo(toDo.concat(value));
        }
      }, [toDo]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (toDo[0] !== undefined) {
          setToDo(
            toDo.filter((item) => {
              return !ids.includes(item._Id);
            })
          );
        }
      }, [filter_items]);
    
      function addIds(checked, id_to_be_deleted) {
        if (!checked) {
          setIds((item) => [...item, id_to_be_deleted]);
        } else {
          setIds(
            ids.filter((item) => {
              return item !== id_to_be_deleted;
            })
          );
        }
      }
    
      function addToDos() {
        const id = uuidv4();
    
        setToDo(
          toDo.concat({
            _Id: id,
            value: <PriorityLists id={id} checked={false} addIds={addIds} />,
          })
        );
        setIdsToRefresh(idsToRefresh.concat(id));
      }
    
      function refresh() {
        setToDo(
          toDo.filter((item) => {
            return !idsToRefresh.includes(item._Id);
          })
        );
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="main-content">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row underline">
              <div className="col">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-3 pt-2">
                    <Refresh _refresh={refresh} />
                  </div>
    
                  <div className="col-6 text-center">
                    <Header header={"Tasks"} />
                  </div>
    
                  <div className="col-3 pt-2">
                    <button className="float-right">
                      <Delete
                        setFilterItems={setFilterItems}
                        filter={filter_items}
                      />
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                {toDo.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={item._Id}>
                      <ul>
                        <li>{item.value}</li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>
    
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col pr-4">
                <Add addToDos={addToDos} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Task;
```

Comment: Your first `useEffect` doesn't have any dependency added. And so it will get called everytime there's a change. You might want to add `toDo` there, as a dependency. Do you have a codesandbox example where I can find the whole working code?

Comment: @SiddAjmera I don't have code sandbox. I would have to upload everything manually since I have the codebase in vscode. How would you generally use local storage to store array of objects? Is my approach correct? The issue I'm seeing is most likely occurring with the rendering.

Comment: Have you checked the dev tools to see if anything is actually getting saved to local storage?

Comment: @KyleLambert https://imgur.com/a/GGgMlrt I'm getting this infinite loop error.

Comment: If you are wanting to call that first `useEffect()` only once, you should use and empty array as the dependencies. `useEffect(()=>doSomething(), [])`